# Multiple file attachment and sending through form

Tags: php, ajax, forms

Here are my two `PHP` files for multiple file attachment, But I couldn't get an email for multiple attachments! Here are my two files

*service-form.php*

```php
<form name="mailForm" id="mailForm" method="post" action="./email-script/send_email_service_request.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Request Service or Support">

    <div class="w3-container w3-third" style="padding:0px;">
        <div class="div-plain quarter-padding">

            <div class="input-row">
                <label class="form-field-text">Full Name</label>
                <span id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br />
                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="userName" id="userName" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-row">
                <label class="form-field-text" style="padding-top: 20px;">Company</label>
                <span id="Company-info" class="info"></span><br />
                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="Company" id="Company" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-row">
                <label class="form-field-text">Email Address</label><br />
                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" />

            </div>

            <div class="input-row">
                <label class="form-field-text" style="padding-top: 20px;">Machine Model Number</label>
                <span id="ModelNumber-info" class="info"></span><br />
                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="ModelNumber" id="ModelNumber" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-row">
                <label class="form-field-text">Machine Serial Number</label><br />
                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="SerialNumber" id="SerialNumber" />
                <br>(see nameplate on front leg of system)
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-third" style="padding:0px; ">
        <div class="div-plain quarter-padding" style="">
            <div>

                <p class="form-field-sub-text" style="margin-bottom:0px;"> If requesting technical support for an issue,
                    please provide the following information:

                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p class="form-field-sub-text" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px;">What was in process
                            when the trouble started?</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="form-field-sub-text" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px;">Has anything in your
                            facility or production process changed recently?</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="form-field-sub-text" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px;">What part of the
                            machine is affected?</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="form-field-sub-text" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px;">Is production stopped
                            because of this issue?
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p class="form-field-sub-text" style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px;"> Otherwise, please provide as
                    much detail as possible about your situation and service request.</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-third" style="padding:0px;  ">
        <div class="div-plain quarter-padding" style="">

            <div class="input-row">
                <label class="form-field-text">Details</label><br><textarea name="Message" id="Message"
                    class="input-field" id="Message" cols="60" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>


            <div class="input-row">
                <p class="form-field-text">Supporting Files</p>
                <div class="attachment-row">
                    <input type="file" class="input-field" name="attachment[]" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.xlsx,.xls" />
                </div>

                <div onClick="addMoreAttachment();" class="icon-add-more-attachemnt" title="Add More Attachments"><img
                        src="icon-add-more-attachment.png" alt="Add More Attachments">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn-submit" value="Send Request" />

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="clearfix" style="clear:both"></div>

    <div class="mail-sent-status">
        <div class="status-message"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
</form>


<script>
    //form validation and submit
    $("#mailForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#mailForm").validate({
        rules: {
            userName: {
                required: true
            },
            Company: {
                required: true
            },
            Phone: {
                required: true
            },
            ModelNumber: {
                required: true
            },
            SerialNumber: {
                required: true
            },
            Message: {
                required: true
            },
            userEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var msgHolder = $('.mail-sent-status');
            var url = $(form).attr('action') ;
            var data = $(form).serialize();
            var myForm = document.getElementById('mailForm');
            var formData = new FormData(myForm);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                // data: data,
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend:function () {
                    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
                    // console.log(response)
                    var result = response;
                    // var result = JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(result)
                    if(result.status == false){
                        msgHolder.find('.status-message').removeClass('success').addClass('failed').html(result.message)
                    } else {
                        $(form).trigger("reset");
                        msgHolder.find('.status-message').removeClass('failed').addClass('success').html(result.message)
                    }
                }            
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

and

*send_email_service_request.php*

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

//script use from https://www.codexworld.com/php-contact-form-send-email-with-attachment-on-submit/
$sub = $_POST["subject"];
$userName = $_POST["userName"];
$company = $_POST["Company"];
$userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
$modelNumber = $_POST["ModelNumber"];
$serialNumber = $_POST["SerialNumber"];
$comment = $_POST["Message"];
$uploadedFileType = array();
$uploadedFileName = array();


// Upload attachment file
$uploadStatus = 1;
if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])){

    // File path config
    // $targetDir = dirname(__FILE__)."/email-files/";
    // $fileName = basename($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
    // $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
    // $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // // Allow certain file formats
    // $allowTypes = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xlsx', 'xls');
    // if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    //     // Upload file to the server
    //     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
    //         $uploadedFile[] = $targetFilePath;
    //     } else {
    //         $uploadStatus = 0;
    //         $result['file'] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    //     }
    // } else {
    //     $uploadStatus = 0;
    //     $result['file'] = 'Sorry, only PDF, DOC, Excel files are allowed to upload.';
    // }

    for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['attachment']['name']); $i++){
      $uploadedFileType[] = $_FILES['attachment']['type'][$i];
      $uploadedFileName[] = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i];
    }
}

$files = $uploadedFileName;

$to = "info@online-engineering.com";

// if($uploadStatus == 1){

    // Recipient
    // $to = "azizulh.ilbd@gmail.com";

    // Subject
    $subject = "ONLINE Engineering [".$sub."]";

    // Message
    $htmlContent = '

<html>
<head>
  <title>Sender Information</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 160px;">Name: </th>
      <td style="text-align:left;">'. $userName .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 160px;">Email: </th>
      <td style="text-align:left;">'.$userEmail.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 160px;">Company: </th>
      <td style="text-align:left;">'.$company.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 160px;">Machine Model Number: </th>
      <td style="text-align:left;">'.$modelNumber .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 160px;">Machine Serial Number: </th>
      <td style="text-align:left;">'.$serialNumber.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;width: 160px;" colspan="2">Details: </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;" colspan="2">'.$comment.'</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

    // Header for sender info
    $headers = "From: $userName"." <".$userEmail.">";

    if(!empty($files) && count($files) > 0){

        // Boundary
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        // Headers for attachment
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

        // Multipart boundary
        $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";

        // Preparing attachment
        for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
          $file = @fopen($files[$x],"rb");
          $data = @fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
          @fclose($file);
          $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

          $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
          "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
          $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

          // $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$files[$x]."\"\n" .
          //   "Content-Description: ".$files[$x]."\n" .
          //   "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$files[$x]."\"; size=".filesize($files[$x]).";\n" .
          //   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";

          $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
        }


        // Send email
        $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    } else {
        // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
        $headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
        $headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";

        // Send email
        $mail = mail($to, $subject, $htmlContent, $headers);
    }
// }

    if( $mail ){
      $result['status'] = true;
      $result['message'] = 'Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you.';
      //$result['error'] = $mail->ErrorInfo;
      die(json_encode($result));
    } else {
      $result['status'] = false;
      $result['message'] = 'Your mail has not been sent! There is an error. Please try again.';
      //$result['error'] = $mail;
      die(json_encode($result));
    }

    //die();

      // echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
?>
```

Here is the live http://online-engineering.com/custom-machining.php

Comment: is there any errors?

Comment: No, I didn't get a console error!

Comment: in your php logs?

Comment: No! I did not get an error!